# Firebase - Nested observeSingleEvent query in for loop callback too many time update

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I am facing a serious callback hell on firebase realtime database update.

Situation:
I have comments node which store all the comment's detail information, such as belong to whose userId (uid) , message, and post id (pid). Please see image below.

[image: comments node data structure]

I have another post-comment nodes, which store comments key under each post id key. Please see image below.

[image: post-comment node data structure]

Finally the third nodes is user-comment, which store all comments key under unique user account id key. Please see image below.

[image: user-comment node data structure]

Problem:

Everything work fine on "Write comment" function, because it just create a comment key and update comment data to these nodes.

But, when user call "Delete post" function, which will delete all the comments data belong to this post id. Therefore, I have this code logical to loop all the comments data. The whole point is that first I have to get the post-comment snapshot in order to limitation the query amount on comments node (because comments node store all the app user's comment detail data. Without knowing the quantity of comment belong to the target post, it will need to for loop all over the comments node, it is too overload.)

For looping the post-comment will get the commentKey, then I can set Null on comments node and post-comment node.

But the issues happen on I need to use comments node to find out the userId, in order to set NSNull on user-comment. When I calling the event below:

> commentsRef.child((snap as AnyObject).key).observeSingleEvent(of:
>   .value, with: { (commentSnapshot) in
>
> })

The commentsRef callback scope become another thread. Therefore, if I call rootRef.updateChildValues out side of this scope and in the end of for loop (post-comment) which will only update comments node and post-comment node. The user-comment updates data will still assign key:value on the other thread.

> updates["user-comment/(userId)/comments/(commentKey)"] = NSNull()

I have to put the rootRef.updateChildValue in the

> commentsRef.child((snap as AnyObject).key).observeSingleEvent(of:
>   .value, with: { (commentSnapshot) in
>
> ```
> ...
>
> rootRef.updateChildValues(updates)
> ```
>
> })

This logic will cause updateChildValues being called too many time if the comments over 10,000 or more than 1 million, because it is in the for looping. I use count down method try to call update only once on the for loop end. But the count number always be 0 in the commentRef scope... I don't know why...

Please help me out with a better solution to dealing with this nested observeSingleEvent update issues without changing the current nodes structure. My goal is to only call rootRef.updateChildValue one time.

Thanks for your help.

Demo code:

```
func deleteAllCommentsRelateTo(postId: String, callback: ((CommentServiceError?) -> Void)?) {
        var error: CommentServiceError?
        guard session.isValid else {
            error = .authenticationNotFound(message: "Authentication not found.")
            callback?(error)
            return
        }

        let uid = session.user.id
        let rootRef = Database.database().reference()
        let path1 = "posts/\(postId)/comments_count"
        let path2 = "posts/\(postId)/uid"

        let commentCountRef = rootRef.child(path1)
        let authorRef = rootRef.child(path2)

        authorRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { authorSnapshot in
            guard let authorId = authorSnapshot.value as? String else {
                error = .failedToDelete(message: "Author not found")
                callback?(error)
                return
            }

            if uid != authorId {
                error = .failedToDelete(message: "User has no permission to delete this post comments")
                callback?(error)
                return
            }

            commentCountRef.runTransactionBlock({ (data) -> TransactionResult in

                if let _ = data.value as? Int {
                    data.value = 0
                }
                return TransactionResult.success(withValue: data)

            }) { (err, committed, snapshot) in
                guard err == nil, committed else {
                    error = .failedToDelete(message: "Unable to delete a comment")
                    callback?(error)
                    return
                }

                var updates: [AnyHashable: Any] = [:]

                    /**
                     * [CHECKED] Set NSNull() on comments, post-comment, and user-comment nodes.
                     */
                    let commentsRef = rootRef.child("comments")
                    let postCommentRef = rootRef.child("post-comment")
                    let query = postCommentRef.child(postId).child("comments").queryOrderedByKey()

                    query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (data) in
                        guard data.hasChildren() else {
                            error = .failedToDelete(message: "No comments data")
                            callback?(error)
                            return
                        }

                        var count = data.childrenCount

                        print("post-comment count!!!!!!!: ", data.childrenCount)

                        for snap in data.children {
                            guard let commentKeySnap = snap as? DataSnapshot else {
                                continue
                            }

                            count -= 1

                            let commentKey = commentKeySnap.key

                            if count == 0 {
                                print("this is totally not right!!!!!")
                            }

                            updates["comments/\(commentKey)"] = NSNull()
                            updates["post-comment/\(postId)/comments/\(commentKey)"] = NSNull()

                            commentsRef.child((snap as AnyObject).key).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (commentSnapshot) in
                                guard let userId = commentSnapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "uid").value as? String else {
                                    return
                                }


                                updates["user-comment/\(userId)/comments/\(commentKey)"] = NSNull()

                                print("In this observeSingleEvent will always be 0 count::::: ", count)

                                if count == 0 {
rootRef.updateChildValues(updates, withCompletionBlock: { err, ref in
                                            guard err == nil else {
                                                error = .failedToDelete(message: "Failed to delete comment")
                                                callback?(error)
                                                return
                                            }
                                        })

                                    print("deleteAllComments: ", updates)
                                    callback?(nil)
                                }
                            })
                            print("count down: ", count)
                        }
                    })
                })
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

I accidentally found out the correct place to put count -= 1. Originally I put it in the for loop scope, but the count did not decrease in the commentRef in scope. Therefore, I put count -= 1 in the commentRef scope which success count to zero and only call rootRef.update one time.